# Changing item in list by index in TCL

Tags: arrays, list, file, tcl

Im trying to work with this awful language and I have to change an item of list by accessing to it with index

```
set FileRead [open "$flPath" r]
set Data [read $FileRead]
set DataList [split $Data "\n"] #Guess that it creates a list, not an array right?

for {set i 1} { $i < [llength $DataList]} {incr i} {
     set line [lindex $DataList $i]
     #Some changes on $line
     lreplace $DataList $i $line # Thought this should replace the DataList[$i] with my $line
}
```

I dont understand the awful syntax of TCL! How can I realise it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are changing every item in a list, and the new value can be produced by a simple script, `lmap` (list map) is the way to go. The command creates a list with the same number of items as the original list, where each item in the new list has the value of the script with the value of the corresponding item in the original list inserted. Say you want to count characters for each item in a list:

```
set list [list can be produced]
lmap item $list {
    list $item [string length $item]
}
# => {{can 3} {be 2} {produced 8}}
```

Note that this command does not change the value of `list`: you need to assign it back to update the value.

The `linsert` (list insert) adds new items to a list without removing any of the existing elements:

```
set list [list can be produced]
linsert $list 1 not
# => {can not be produced}
```

The `lreplace` (list replace) is mostly useful for insertions that change the number of elements in a list:

```
set list [list can be produced]
lreplace $list 0 1 can sometimes but not always be
# => {can sometimes but not always be produced}

set list [list the new value can be produced]
lreplace $list 1 1
# => {the value can be produced}
```

Again, the value of `list` isn't changed by `linsert` or `lreplace`.

If you want to change an item in a list in place, `lset` (list set) is your friend:

```
set list [list the new value can be produced]
lset list 1 correct
# => {the correct value can be produced}
```

This command *does* change the value of `list`, because it belongs to the family of setting commands that take a variable name rather than a variable value, and modify the value in some way.

Documentation: [linsert](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/linsert.htm), [list](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/list.htm), [lmap](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/lmap.htm), [lreplace](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/lreplace.htm), [lset](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/lset.htm), [set](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/set.htm), [string](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/string.htm)

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't just call a language awful because you don't know how to use it, otherwise, just don't use it at all...

In any case, you should read the [documentation](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/lreplace.htm) of `lreplace`. You supply:

```
lreplace list first last ?element element ...?
```

To replace the line in the list of `DataList`, you thus should change your line to:

```
lreplace $DataList $i $i $line
```

This will replace the `i`th item in `DataList` with the string in `line`.

However, this will not change the list `DataList` at all you need to `set` the result of the `lreplace` to a variable (`lreplace` does not alter the list `DataList` directly) like...

```
set DataList [lreplace $DataList $i $i $line]
```

---

Though if you are changing only one item in the list at a time, it would be better to use [`lset`](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/lset.htm):

```
set FileRead [open "$flPath" r]
set Data [read $FileRead]
set DataList [split $Data "\n"] #Guess that it creates a list, not an array right?

for {set i 1} { $i < [llength $DataList]} {incr i} {
     set line [lindex $DataList $i]
     # Some changes on $line
     lset DataList $i $line
}
```

`lset` unlike `lreplace` does not need to be set since it changes the list in addition to returning the substituted list.

Comment: why DataList is not changed? Im substituting the $line in the code before appending it back to the list

Comment: @Rocker Let's say you have the list `{5 4 3}`. When `i = 1` in the first loop, `[lindex $DataList 1]` will give `4` (Tcl is 0 based). `lreplace $DataList 1 1 4` will replace the element with index `1` with the value of `4`... which was already 4.

Comment: @Jerry, Since `lreplace` takes a list **value** and not a **variable**, it cannot alter the DataList variable. You need to show how to reassign the results back to the same variable. +1 for your first sentence

Comment: @glennjackman Yes, that too, sometimes I forget that lreplace doesn't alter the list though I use it properly in my scripts oops. Thanks!

Comment: I think you need to show him `set DataList [lreplace $DataList ...]` to make it clear. Also, mention `lset` if he's using tcl 8.4 and above

Comment: @slebetman I'll add the `set` one. The `lset` one, I would rather wait to get clarification on what OP is trying to do exactly. Even if OP did the command right, it still wouldn't change the contents of the list. =/

Comment: Since he's confused why the contents of the list didn't change it could be safely assumed that he wants it changed. So `lset` is appropriate. Indeed the `set Datalist [lreplace ..]` does the same thing as `lset`.

Comment: @slebetman Even so, the list won't change as he would be replacing the contents of the list with themselves.

Comment: @Jerry: See the comment `# Some changes on $line`. Never ignore comments!

Comment: @slebetman To think that I read all other comments except that very one... >~< Added it. Didn't mention the Tcl version because I haven't seen any question before 8.4 recently and 8.4 should be substituted for 8.5 as far as possible anyway.